# BigQuery vs QlikView - Direct Discovery not support TABLE_QUERY

Tags: google-bigquery, qlikview

we want to view BigQuery with QlickView Direct Discovery.

we didn't find a way to view tables with  TABLE_QUERY,
we only found option to view on single table, what's it's huge problem when investigate against big data.

Does anyone found solution or workaround in order to view multi tables with TABLE_QUERY ?

Comment: I have no idea about QlickView so I don't understand your question well enough, but if you could elaborate more on what you'd like to achieve on BigQuery, I'll try to help you.

Comment: it's regarding more to QlickView than to BigQuery, thanks!